# Updating Ruby via RVM issue, seems to be a problem with libxml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I was about to start my first Rails 3 app and thought I would upgrade to the latest version of ruby before I did and the ruby fails to make correctly.

I'm using Snow leopard on the 32bit kernal at the moment and every time I try and run 1.9.2 whether it's through readline or ssl I still get the following error:

```
ld: warning: in ../../libruby.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../../.ext/i386-darwin10.5.0/tcltklib.bundle] Error 1
```

I tried using the 64 kernal using this among other as a guide http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2010/07/08/installing-ruby-1-9-2-with-rvm-on-snow-leopard/  but then I get a similar message saying libxml1.dylib is failing because it's not set up to 64bit.

Has anyone got any ideas? it's driving me nuts...

Comment: now getting this error: -
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libxslt.1.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your Ruby is 64-bit, and the native gem drivers match it. `ruby -v` on 64-bit Snow Leopard should display:

```
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.5.0]
```

Your gems will complain about the architecture, returning the `i386` fingerprint when there is a mismatch. To fix that you can try:

```
gem pristine --all
```

which should walk through all gems and reload them from the clean cached versions. In that process any native drives should be rebuilt.

Answer (score 1):

Ok for anyone having the same issue as me I would suggest going to 64bit kernal - if your not sure how go [here](http://macperformanceguide.com/SnowLeopard-64bit.html)

I would then follow this excellent [blog post](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2010/07/08/installing-ruby-1-9-2-with-rvm-on-snow-leopard/)

The only other thing I need to do above this post was as well as updating libxml I also had to update libxlst (which you can download from the same source).  Once I ran the install checked it was pointing to the the correct kernal then everything updated fine.

Hope that helps anyone having the same issue!

Comment: The blog post you reference worked for me as well.  I used `brew install libxml2` and `brew link libxml2` to get libxml2 on 64 bit, and then did the same set of commands for libxslt.  The --readline portion was important as well, as I used the readline from brew.